# Prevent ion-fab-list from closing when selecting element in it

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I'm trying to make a form pop up when a fab is clicked. I'm using ionic 4 but each time a fab or other component in the `ion-fab-list` is clicked. the `ion-fab-list` automatically closes. How can i click on an element and prevent it from closing

i have tried using `@ViewChild`but it doesn't work. One thing i have noted about the `@ViewChild`decorator is that it required two parameters which i have not seen other solution do.

form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonFab } from '@ionic/angular'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss'],
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  isFabListOpen = false

  toggleFab(): void {
    this.isFabListOpen = !this.isFabListOpen
    console.log('lol')
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

form.component.scss

```
ion-fab {
  position: fixed;
  left: 84%;
  float: right;
}

ion-fab-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 350px;
  right: 130px;
}
```

form.component.html

```
<ion-fab horizontal="end" vertical="bottom" slot="fixed" [activated]="isFabListOpen">
  <ion-fab-button color="light" (click)="toggleFab()">
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top" [hidden]="isFabListOpen">
    <!-- <ion-fab-button color="light">
      <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-button color="light">
      <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-button color="light">
      <ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button> -->
    <form action="">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>quote</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Awesome Input"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>author</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Awesome Input"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>author</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Awesome Input"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>day</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MM YY" placeholder="Leave empty to select today"></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-button>
        Save
      </ion-button>
    </form>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

The fab list should still remain even when clicking on the fabs or components but instead close when clicked.

Comment: Post your ts code that includes ```toggleFab()```

Comment: I've included it

Answer (score 0):

You could reopen another fab immediately with the same data as soon as it is clicked. It will look like it never went away =D

Answer (score 0):

Remove `toggleFab()` from the button. `ion-fab-button` does the same thing. You don't need the function to trigger it to close or open. You actually don't even need to include the `activated` attribute unless you're using it somewhere else because it defaults to false.
Here's what's happening under the hood:

1. Hitting `ion-fab-button` changes `isFabListOpen` & `activated` to `true`
2. Fab opens
3. `toggleFab()` fires, `this.isFabListOpen = !this.isFabListOpen`
4. `isFabListOpen` & `activated` is now false
5. Modal is now closed

Answer (score 0):

I did it using JavaScript like this:

```html
<ion-fab class="remote_controller" vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="game-controller"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <ion-fab-button id="up" onclick="stop_close(this)">
      <ion-icon name="caret-up"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab-list>
  <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
    <ion-fab-button id="down" onclick="stop_close(this)">
      <ion-icon name="caret-down"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab-list>
  <ion-fab-list side="start">
    <ion-fab-button id="left" onclick="stop_close(this)">
      <ion-icon name="caret-back"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab-list>
  <ion-fab-list side="end">
    <ion-fab-button id="right" onclick="stop_close(this)">
      <ion-icon name="caret-forward"></ion-icon>
      </ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

and

```html
<script>
  function stop_close(event){
    $('.remote_controller')[0].activated = false;

    //do stuff with the button
  }
</script>
```